# list all widget android

Tags: android, android-studio

In the palette of `AndroidStudio` editor some `Widgets` are indicated, but not all.

For example, on the net I just found an Android widget named `Datepicker`.

How to have all widget names available in Android for be able to use these.

Answer (score 0):

The platform widgets are contained in the `android.widget` package in the platform. You can see the list of those in the documentation at:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary

There are also widgets contained in the support libraries as well and they're currently mostly in the `android.support.v7.widget` package which you can see the docs for at:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/package-summary

In the near future these will be moving into the `androidx` package but that is still a work in progress